# Accessing URL params in parent components

Tags: react-router

I've got an interesting conundrum that I'd like some insight on. I've got a routing setup like follows:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path='/' component={Main}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path='foo' component={FooContainer}>
      <Route path='bars/:barId' component={BarDetailsContainer} />
      <Route path='baz/:bazId' component={BazDetailsContainer} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='things' component={ThingListContainer}>
      <Route path='thing/:thingId' component={ThingDetailsContainer} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

And it works by and large. FooContainer has a child of its own (not via `this.props.children`), which wants to know what `:barId` is (and `:bazId`) when those components are loaded via their respective routes. Is there a way to access *all* of the current params -- including the URL params for its child routes -- from the "parent" component, `FooContainer`?

Note: it is also possible that I am doing this *entirely wrong*, in which case, I would love some advice on a better way to accomplish my goal here.

Answer (score 0):

An answer, for those concerned:

Turns out I was looking for `this.props.params` in a *child* of `Main` that is not managed by any `Route`, and as such, I'd need to *explicitly* pass the `params` prop (or whichever params are important) down to it from `Main`.

My `Main`'s implementation, as a rough JSX sketch, looks like:

```
<div>
    <SomeOtherComponentThatWantsParams />
    {this.props.children}
</div>
```